# Buffered Reader not reading

Tags: java, android, file-io

```
    private void monthlyInput() throws IOException {
        File inFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory       ().getAbsolutePath(), "S050213.txt");

        String data = inFile.getAbsolutePath();
        TextView testData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        testData.setText(data);

        FileInputStream fInStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);


        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fInStream));

        String data2 = myReader.readLine();

        TextView testData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        testData2.setText(data2);

        myReader.close();

    }
```

I know this is finding the file because data is outputting the correct file path, but data2 seems to be empty. My best guess is that it isn't finding the file at

```
FileInputStream fInStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
```

I'm wondering where I am going wrong, or if I am even close to where I should be.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? If not, your file probably exists, but is empty

Comment: before reading check whether file exists or not.. `if(inFile.exists())` then only do stuff

Comment: If there is an exception check permission

Comment: I added in the if statement and it goes to the else, so I assume this means there is an exception.  I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in the Manifest.xml, do I need to do something else for permission?

Comment: Does logcat show any exception for your app?  Also your code will only read the first line of the text file, why not use a while() loop and output the lines read to the log so you have more information about whether the correct file is being read.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Pragnani Why? The code will throw a FileNotFoundException. Checking exists() as well adds nothing.

Comment: @EJP Sorry for late reply...File he created from sd card path, may or may not exist, just to make sure that he is reading the file which exist in SD card I have suggested that, And I don't mention in comment that, that wiil fix the issue, it was a plain suggestion..thank you very much for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks fine. Seems like issue reading the file. 
Are you sure it's being saved properly. Try placing a file with some random text with different unique name - manually in your external storage directory and try reading it with same code.

Comment: Tried putting a different text file on the device, and that read fine.  Then I removed the file I need and put it back on the device and it is reading fine now. Still not sure what the problem was, but thanks for pointing me to the file rather than the code.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but I have one more question. Can I specify to read the file from downloads directory which is in the same directory as the file is currently?

Comment: You can try Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);